# Web API C# - Validar token gerado por outro servidor

Tags: c#, oauth

Tenho uma api OAth basico, ela só gera o token, está em localhost:1010/Token

Tenho uma api com os métodos de regra negócio, está em localhost:2020/api

Como faço para validar se um token é válido dentro da api na :2020 ?

Obrigado.